# WCF - How to use IDataSurrogate to exclude the data member depends on client requirement

Tags: wcf

Consider I have a DataContract with 6 properties. one client needs first 3 properties and second client needs last 3 properties of the Data Contract. How to write the Data Contract in a service So that the Service sends the message with only Required properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is creating separate service for each client. Each service will expose operation using its own data contract with only required properties. Both services will be just wrapper around your core logic working with whole data object. If the reason for sending only subset of properties is data security then creating two services is the only valid option.

If we consider this more detaily the problem here is service description. If you expose metadata / WSDL on your service it will always contain the whole data contract because you can't change it dynamically. If a client creates proxy from these metadata it will also receive whole contract.

You can avoid sending some properties in SOAP message if you configure your contract [to not include properties with default values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue.aspx) and do not set them in your service but I don't think it is a good solution.

Comment: The thing is Client knows about whole Data Contract that is exposed from metadata. But he will request only required properties and all remaining properties should not be sent with service reply message.    Is above mentioned scenario is best or shall i need to use DataContract Surrogate to achieve that?

Comment: Isn't it easier simply create to different operation returning subsets of data?

Comment: If the number of clients for service increases then its a problem. Each client has his own requirements. Is there any good solution for this?

Comment: If each client has their own requirement they must either receive all data and use only data they need or you must create specific operation for each client. Other possibility can be defining base datacontract with data for all clients and specific derived data contract for each client. You will have single operation returning data based on connected client.